# how to add new client to snapbill with its API

Tags: php, curl

I have been trying to use the API of SnapBill from PHP. I am just trying to make a new client for every action of a form post.

[The documentation of the SnapBill clients API](http://docs.snapbill.com/developers/api/client) did not help me.

Comment: Show some code that you have tried.

Comment: There is updated documentation available at: http://docs.snapbill.com/developers/start

Answer (score 1):

I used this API recently and if you're new to REST (like me), the documentation doesn't really make any sense. The API is based on RESTful design so I used cURL library of PHP for sending and getting requests from the API.

This post http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2008/using-curl-and-php-to-talk-to-a-rest-service helped me a lot. Hope you get the idea.